# Renaming every file in a directory, based off first line

Tags: ruby, file, rename

Starting out in Ruby and trying to create a simple renaming Ruby script. Say I have a directory filled with resumes with randomized filenames like: Resume0001, Resume0012, Resume9123, Res_430. In general it doesn't matter what the starting name is.

I want my script to take in every file and rename (or create a new file) with the name of the file as the name of the resume owner. I understand that it depends on the resume layout of course, but, I am assuming that the first line will hold only the name of that person.

Given what I know, I am able to rename them by feeding in the arguments (files) manually. This would be fine if I only had like 5 resumes to do. My problem comes up when I try to feed my script a directory of about 10,000 resumes.

This is what I have so far:

```
puts "Renaming files..."

Dir.glob("Resumes") do |f|
    File.rename(f, f.readline())
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

I have a couple ideas why this doesn't work/things I'm not sure about:

1. `f` is just a String, not a file object which is why `readline()` doesn't work on it. (edit: f == filename, not a reference to the actual file object)
2. I'm also getting a private method error. This also happens if I try something like

   `first_line = f.readline()
    File.rename(f, first_line)`

   I'm just having difficulties understanding what exactly the private method error is.
3. I'm not entirely sure how specifying directory paths work. So let's say my .rb file is located `documents\name\resume_converter\converter.rb`. If my directory of resumes is also in the `resume_converter` folder (`resume_converter\Resumes`), I would specify it in `Dir.glob("Resumes")`? What if it was another file deeper? `resume_converter\Dummy_folder\Resumes` => `Dir.glob("Dummy_folder\Resumes")`?
4. Is there framework support for what I'm trying to do? I have no practical Rails/framework knowledge but I imagine that a task like this has been done before using a framework?

So yeah, I'm stuck.

Comment: Are these text files? Usually resumes are in word format, isn't?

Comment: Yeah, but, for simplicity/practice sake, I was hoping to just try it with plain text files.

Comment: So the assumption is, they are text files and the first line has some text (and not one or more blank lines).

Comment: Yeah, if it's not clear:  The first line only has the full name of that person before a new line, and the rest of the content starts. Sorry about that.

Comment: What happens if two people named "John Smith" send in resumes?

Comment: @theTinMan You're absolutely right, it will be a problem, it's just I figured for now I get it to at least output the right contents. I could polish it afterwards. I figure a simple "does this file name exist already, if so, add 1 to the file name" method wouldnt be that hard to add afterwards.

Comment: I'd recommend using a database, rather than disk, to keep the files' content. Then it's easy to use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and a table to map the filename to the record. You could use a randomized string, or an incrementing serial number, but there are limitations to those that always bother me, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob("Resumes/*").each do |f|
  name = File.open(f).readlines.first.strip # Strip off any whitespace or trailing newlines
  FileUtils.mv(f, "Resumes/#{name}")
end
```

Comment: So I can understand what the code is doing, but, I'm getting a `rename': permission denied` error.

Comment: I guess I don't have permission to rename a file while it's open or something to that effect? Would it be better to just write a new file with the first line? Something like `new_file = File.open(name, "w")
new_file.write(f.read())`?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting a permission denied error.  I ran this successfully myself before posting it.  Do you have the proper permissions on both the Resumes directory and the files you are trying to move?

Comment: It's probably just because this workstation doesn't have admin privileges. Tested your response on another one with admin, and it worked.